# as3 movieclip loop play based on variable

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, animation

I have 1 movieclips with 2 animations in them:

- Idle (from frame 15)
- Dance (from frame 44)

I want to loop each movieclip animation if a condition on a variable is met:

- dance = 0; // idle animation must occur.
- dance = 1; // dance animation should occur.

I have tried the following:

```
    if (n <= 1) {
        dance = false;
        anim.gotoAndPlay(15);
    } else if (n > 1) {
        dance = true;
        anim.gotoAndPlay(44);
    }
```

That code is on an enterframe event, which just gives me the 1st frame of animation, the thing is I don't know how can I fix this?

Regards.

Comment: Can you explain us what is `n` here please ?

Comment: Sure, n is a variable I'm using (based on audio analysis). Range goes from 1 to about 12.

It changes very often in a small amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's on an enterFrameEvent then every frame it's either going to try and play from frame 15 or 44. I say try because the very next frame it's going to go to either 15 or 44 again...and again etc.

You need to trigger that conditional only when a change occurs and not every frame.